# Moment.js - UTC date to millis since unix epoch

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to get an UTC Date using the moment.js library (just to send it to my server), as follows:

```
const eighteenYearsAgoUTC = moment().utc().subtract(18, "years").toDate();
const eighteenYearsAgoUTCSinceUnixEpoch = eighteenYearsAgoUTC.valueOf()
console.log(eighteenYearsAgoUTCSinceUnixEpoch);
```

> The millis since unix epoch are: 1051875596343

But... if I do the same without utc, I get the same result

```
const eighteenYearsAgoUTC = moment().subtract(18, "years").toDate();
const eighteenYearsAgoUTCSinceUnixEpoch = eighteenYearsAgoUTC.valueOf()
console.log(eighteenYearsAgoUTCSinceUnixEpoch);
```

> 1051875596343

Why am I getting the same milliseconds since Unix Epoch for an UTC date and a local Date?

My local date is: Fri May 02 2003 13:37:00 GMT+0200 (Central Europe)

Answer (score 1):

The [`utc` method](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) just changes how moment *parses* and *formats* dates. The underlying information is still the same.

Milliseconds-since-The-Epoch values are always UTC. Both of your code snippets do the same thing:

- Get "now"
- Subtract 18 years
- Get the result as the milliseconds-since-The-Epoch value

You'd notice a difference if you were formatting a date or parsing one, but you aren't doing either of those things.